# Unable to activate virtual environments on Windows 10 with Python 3.7 using cmd

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, cmd, python-venv

I am having a problem with activating a virtual environment by the name FYP using cmd on Windows 10. I checked the bat file, which is of 1KB size.
See the below commands or image. It should have (FYP) on the start after running the activate.bat file.

[image]

```
C:\Users\Manish>M:
M:\>ENV\FYP\Scripts\activate.bat
M:\>
```

But using a similar command in PowerShell or VS code will get the environment activated.
Check the below image or command. It is showing (FYP) on the start of the command, and FYP env is now activated.

[image]

```
PS M:\> cd .\ENV\
PS M:\ENV> .\FYP\Scripts\activate
(FYP) PS M:\ENV> cd ..
(FYP) PS M:\> cd .\projects\
```

Earlier when I had Windows 7, the virtual environment was getting activated on both PowerShell and cmd as well. And I used similar commands in both cmd and PowerShell.

```
M:\ENV>FYP\Scripts\activate
```

But with Windows 10, I don't know why it is not getting activated on cmd.
Please help?
Is there any specific reason why the virtual environment is not activating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, I can easily activate it through Visual Studio Code's terminal(Powershell), using the command

```
<PATH_TO_VENV>\Scripts\activate
```

<PATH_TO_VENV>: where you have created the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

The command line needs to know where to start. Add .\ to tell it that start in the current directory.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)>".\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```